# error insert "has no column"

Tags: android, sqlite

I have some code in my application, but when I insert a table I get an error. I
 don't know why. Can any one help me??

This is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tambahpenerima);

    data = new dbHelper(this);
    db = data.getWritableDatabase();
    data.createTable(db);

    na = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.na);
    no = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no);
    pesanx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hasilx);

    Bundle paket = getIntent().getExtras();
    nama = paket.getString("nama");
    nomor = paket.getString("nomor");
    hasil = paket.getString("chiper");
    na.setText(nama);
    no.setText(nomor);
    pesanx.setText(hasil);

    pesanKeluar objk = new pesanKeluar(nama, nomor, hasil);
    inputDataK(db, objk);   //here the error    
}
public void inputDataK(SQLiteDatabase db, pesanKeluar k) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nama", k.getNama());
    cv.put("nomortlp", k.getNomorTlp()); //here my modified
    cv.put("chiperteks", k.getChiperteks()); //here my modified
    db.insert("pesanKeluar", null, cv); //here my modified
    db.close();
}
}
```

I've modified my code, but I got the same error as before. Please take a look at my log error.

```
    03-11 17:27:33.704: I/Database(1664): sqlite returned: error code = 
1, msg = table pesanKeluar has no column named chiper
    03-11 17:27:33.725: E/Database(1664): Error inserting 
chiper=00010101 nama=D nomor=536
    03-11 17:27:33.725: E/Database(1664): 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table pesanKeluar has no column
 named chiper: , while compiling: INSERT INTO pesanKeluar(chiper, nama, 
nomor) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

Here is my dbHelper.java:

```
package com.databasesms;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbenkripsisms.db";

public dbHelper ( Context context) {
    super ( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

public void createTable ( SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists tbPesan (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, plainteks TEXT, key TEXT, chiperteks TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists pesanMasuk (id_pm INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, nomortlp NUMBER, plainteks TEXT, key TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists pesanKeluar (id_pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, nomortlp TEXT, chiperteks TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onCreate ( SQLiteDatabase arg0 ) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade ( SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2 ) {

}


}
```

Here is my pesanKeluar.java:

```
package com.databasesms;

public class pesanKeluar {
private String nama;
private String nomortlp;
private String chiperteks;

public pesanKeluar () {
    super();
}

public pesanKeluar ( String nama, String nomortlp, String chiperteks ) {
    this.nama = nama;
    this.nomortlp = nomortlp;
    this.chiperteks = chiperteks;       
}

public String getNama () {
    return nama;
}

public void setNama ( String nama ) {
    this.nama = nama;
}

public String getNomorTlp () {
    return nomortlp;
}

public void setNomorTlp ( String nomortlp ) {
    this.nomortlp = nomortlp;
}

public String getChiperteks () {
    return chiperteks;
}

public void setChiperteks ( String chiperteks ) {
    this.chiperteks = chiperteks;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the above said solutions like replacing the column name and after that just clear your data before relaunching the application.

Comment: how can i clear my data? i dont know where is my database location. i've search on file explore but i dont find.

Comment: Go to settings>>apps>>select your app name>> in detail you can have an option to clear data.

Answer (score 0):

**“has no column”** error clearly states that, the column is not present the table you specified. So either you are referring to wrong table or you have mis-spelled your column name. In your case you have mis-spelled the column name. While creating table you have named fourth column as `chiperteks` and while inserting data into this column you are refering it as `chiper` which is totally wrong.

Change is as below, then it will start working,

```
public void inputDataK(SQLiteDatabase db, pesanKeluar k) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nama", k.getNama());
    cv.put("nomor", k.getNomorTlp());
    cv.put("chiperteks", k.getChiperteks());  // Change here
    db.insert("pesanKeluar", "nama", cv); //here the error
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: i've tried that to, but i got the same error like before. i really dont know why. can u help me?

Comment: @niaa, i saw, but i think this line `hasil = paket.getString("chiper");` also need same change.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the coulmn name `chiperteks` not  `chiper`  `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists pesanKeluar (id_pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, nomortlp TEXT, chiperteks TEXT);");`

Answer (score 0):

table pesanKeluar has no column named chiper

The error says it all your table pesanKeluar has a column name chiperteks... and you are giving a key "chiper" to insert.

Answer (score 0):

> Error inserting chiper=00010101 nama=D nomor=536 03-11 17:27:33.725: E/Database(1664): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table pesanKeluar has no column named chiper: , while compiling: INSERT INTO pesanKeluar(chiper, nama, nomor) VALUES(?, ?, ?);

Its occured when column in your function is not same as in database, check your database whether `chiper named colume` is exist or not or its same spell as you have in your database?

you defines column name as `chiperteks` while creating table and when inserting data you are passing wrong as `chiper`, thats cause error.

Use:

> cv.put("chiperteks", k.getChiperteks());

Instead:

> cv.put("chiper", k.getChiperteks());

Comment: I have changed chiper to chiperteks but i got the same error. any solution more?

Comment: then cross check whether table is create or not? and compare your table columns with your insertion function.

Answer (score 0):

you have the column name `chiperteks` but not `chiper` in your table `pesanKeluar`

replace

```
cv.put("chiper", k.getChiperteks());
```

to

```
cv.put("chiperteks", k.getChiperteks());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void inputDataK(SQLiteDatabase db, pesanKeluar k) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("nama", k.getNama());
        cv.put("nomortlp ", k.getNomorTlp()); // column name should be same as you define in Table
        cv.put("chiperteks ", k.getChiperteks());
        db.insert("pesanKeluar ", null, cv); 
        db.close();
    }
```